# Read newly appended lines to csv file using python or java

Tags: java, python

Jmeter creates csv file at starting of the test, after that Jmeter appends incremental results (new lines) to csv file till test is done. Below is the format

```
1459239209060,152,Client token ,200,OK,data 
1459239209074,136,Client token ,200,OK,data 
1459239209217,17,/mydata,200,OK,data 1
1459239209219,70,/mydata,200,OK,data 1
1459239209235,14,/mydata,200,OK,data 1
```

So I want to read only newly appended values for every time (gap of 1 sec/2 sec /3sec). So is there any way to do this.

Comment: You can store the id/timestamp of last read record somewhere and start reading from there..

Comment: I need to calculate average on column two for every second

Answer (score 0):

Run your JMeter script via [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) framework, it fully supports JMeter .jmx files and reports interim statistics on average response times in console:

[image: Taurus console]

Taurus is an [open-source tool](https://github.com/Blazemeter/taurus) so you can check i.e. https://github.com/Blazemeter/taurus/blob/master/bzt/modules/console.py for implementation details if you need just that bit.